# Is it possible to get the pc/java version of Minecraft for free after buying it from the Windows 10 store?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to get Minecraft (pc/java) for free after purchasing windows 10 version?

Comment: I do think the offer is one directional only (Java -> Win10/Pocket version for free).. not an answer though because I am not 100% sure.

Comment: No; it is not possible to get the legacy Java version for free

Comment: It's not "legacy", it's a full product in active development with plans for the future.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you get Minecraft Java for free if you have purchased Minecraft Bedrock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/389361/can-you-get-minecraft-java-for-free-if-you-have-purchased-minecraft-bedrock)

Answer (score 2):

No, Microsoft and Mojang have stated that the versions are different, so if you want to play both, you have to pay for both.

They are essentially different products.

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible to do the opposite: If you buy Minecraft Java, you can get a free copy of the Windows 10 edition [here](https://account.mojang.com/me).